# Can we apply policy-based design in java?

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics

I've just read about Alexandrescu's policy based design and have a question about whether we can apply such an approach in Java. Let me give you an example (from modern c++ design):

```
template <class T>
struct OpNewCreator{

    static T* Create()
    {
        return new T;
    }
};


template <class CreationPolicy>
class WidgetManager : public CreationPolicy
{
    ...
}; 

typedef WidgetManager<OpNewCreator> MyWidgetMgr;
```

So, as far as I know templates are being instantiated during the compile-time. Similarly, in Java, type erasure applies during compilation. In our production if we need to implement `StrategyPattern` we use the standard GoF-like implementation and honestly, I've never seen such an example in Java. Is it ever possible/useful?

UPD: Of course, in Java we can't instantiate a type variable in that way, but we can use reflection in that case.

[Wiki page about policies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design)

Comment: @Turtle Thank you, but was supposed to look at more exhaustive answer than yes or no :)

Comment: What is "policy-based design"? And what problem(s) does it solve? Including relevant external links in questions is good. (I think this might have more to do with static methods and [lack of] polymorphism around such than generics.)

Comment: Can you clarify if you're talking about Strategy Pattern here or just mentioning it? I'm writing the Strategy Pattern in Java right now, but it doesn't look like that, other than the obvious language differences.

Comment: @user2864740 I've included the external link.

Comment: @stella That doesn't look like the posted code (it is a big difference when static is involved).. anyway I would generally solve such a task in Java (or C#) using Dependency Injection of the 'policies'.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yes, in that particular case I'm talking about StrategyPattern implementation in Java. I know how it may be implemented. I'm interested in whether it can be implemented in the way as Alexandrescu describes in his book for c++.

Comment: @user2864740 No, I think DI has nothing to do with my concern. Just to be metnioned, we use Spring IoC and I don't see what you tried to say...

Comment: Well, following the example in the link, it would be (for 1:1 example): `HelloWorld  hello_world = new HelloWorld(new OutputPolicyWriteToCout(), new LanguagePolicyEnglish())`. The main difference is where the polymorphism occurs (in C++ it's structual polymorphism at compile-time, in Java it is subtype polymorphism, hopefully with interfaces). However this question is not what is shown in the example and has additional complications, mainly with introducing static and creating a new type.

Comment: THe title of the question ssems misleading.  If I understand well, it's not about implementing policies in general with generics, but more about circumventing the limitations of java generics that prevent SOME of Alexandrescu's policies, isn't it ?  I suggest then that you change the title to make it more specific.

Comment: You may want to read thins article about policies vs DI: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/dependency-injection-and-policy-based-de/228701135